# Get high I/O rate alert from linode.com,how to location problem?

Tags: linux, linode

Today I get an  alert mail from linode.com "Your Linode, Randy, has exceeded the notification threshold (1000) for disk io rate by averaging 1571.81 for the last 2 hours.".

Last time I get alert like that is several month ago, I keeping get alerts, but at the same time my website network traffic never grow. I try everything, but can not location the problem. Finally, I guess the growing log file size is the problem. I use cronolog cut log file, and problem resolved.

Now,I/O rate chart shows I/O rate is keeping growing too, how to I  location problem? Is there anything can help me?

My server is Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS/apache/php/mysql at linode.com.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can determine which process is thrashing your disk using the iotop package. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=876738

Also, you can change the I/O rate alert threshold in the Settings tab of the Linode web interface.

Comment: Can I determine which file is write or read?

Comment: Once you see which process is writing, you can use 'sudo lsof | grep process_name' to see which files it has open.

Answer (score 1):

Try *vmstat* and see if there's much bi/bo.
I thought it is caused by swap thrashing, due to the small physical memory of your Linode.

Comment: bi=2,bo =4.

I don't think so, because seems memory is never run out.

Answer (score -1):

1st，you may be find the problem , mysql or apache
using    vmstat    iostat

2nd, if problem from apache  ,  you can  using nginx ＋fastcgi to  replace apache
      it is a light web server, better than apache

```
 if problem  from mysql  ，you can modify  my.cnf
```

3rd  if problem from other app? please  paste your log file

Comment: point is how to use vmstat or iostat find problem from what app? I just can see some global info, not info about a app.